# Скрипт поиска файлов в Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Всем привет нужно написать скрипт который,
Будет искать во всех подкаталогах файлы которые мы указали в аргументах скрипта
Когда мы найдем файл нужно выводить сообщение "Файл который назывется ... находится в папке ..."

Может для кого-то это изи пизи но в Bash я полный ноль
вот что у меня получилось сделать самому

```
#! bin/bash

echo "File name?"
read name
dir="$(basename $name)"
find ./ -name $name | awk '{print"plik"$name}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in "$@"; do
    # имя файла с экранированными символами wildcard для поиска по точному имени
    escapedName=`echo "$name" | sed -e 's#\([*?]\|\[\|\]\)#\\\\\1#g'`
    find ./ -name "$escapedName" -printf "Файл '%f' находится в папке '%h'\n"
done
```

Найти файл несложно. Вопрос лишь в том, как искать файлы с символами со специальным значением.

Например, имя файла `*.txt` является вполне легитимным именем в файловой системе. Но если сделать поиск `find . -name '*.txt'`, то `*` будет интепретироваться как шаблон (wildcard). Поэтому перед тем как искать нужно перед каждым спецсимволом ставить `\`.

Для экранирования я предалагаю использовать `sed` скрипт. Он ставит перед `*?[]` обратный слэш. В скрипте целое буйство `\`, так как слэши интерпретируются несколько раз. Во-первых, `\1` означает подставить подстроку, заматченную скобками. Каждая пара `\\` интерпретируется как одинарный `\` в тексте замены. В замене нужно два слэша, так как ещё раз слэши будут интерпретированы шеллом при подстановке переменной "$escapedName". Итого в выражении sed нужны пять `\`.

Для тестирования был создан набор файлов

```
./a/%h.txt
./a/1.txt
./a/b/2.txt
./a/b/c/3.txt
./a/b/".txt
./a/b/*.txt
```

Пример использования

```
./search.sh '*.txt' '%h.txt' '".txt' '1.txt'
Файл *.txt находится в каталоге ./a/b
Файл %h.txt находится в каталоге ./a
Файл ".txt находится в каталоге ./a/b
Файл 1.txt находится в каталоге ./a
```

BTW. в этом ответе нет `read`, так как у вас по условию задания нужно искать файлы из аргументов скрипта.

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать так:

```
#Читаем имя файла
read -p "File name: " name
#Ищем в текущем каталоге с любой вложенностью и печатаем в случае нахождения
find $PWD -name "$name" -printf 'файл %f находится в %h/\n'
#%f - выводит имя файла
#%h - выводит имя директории
#%p - выводит имя директории и файла
```

Важно, что поиск будет идти по полному совпадению, т.е. поиск файла с именем file не найдет file.txt
Варианты поисков:

```
#Поиск по началу имени + полное совпадение
-name "${name}*"
#Поиск по части имени + полное совпадение
-name "*${name}*"
#Поиск по окончанию имени + полное совпадение
-name "*${name}"
```

Так же, что бы исключить из поиска каталоги, следует использовать параметр поиска `-type f`.
Пример:

```
find $PWD -type f -name "*$name*" -printf 'файл %f находится в %h/\n'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не совсем то что мне было нужно нужно указывать в выполнении скрипта названия файлов в качестве аргументов , но ваш вариант тоже хорош, спасибо за старания я ценю это